# Is it long polling or short polling?

Tags: javascript, php, beginner, jquery, sql

I wrote the following script and [php](/questions/tagged/php) code for long-polling architecture by googling references, I would like to know if this is long-polling or short-polling, ...because I am not sure:

**bc_test.js**

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var data = [];
  function pullNotification() {
    var params = {}; 
    new RPC.Call({
        'method': 'users.getJsonUsers',
        'params': params,
        'timeout': 30000,
        'onSuccess': success,
        'onFailure' : error,       
    });
  };

  function error() {
    alert('Error occured');
  }    

  function success(result) {
    if (data.length !== 0) {            
        for (var i = 0, item; item = result[i]; i++) { 
           for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k++) {
               if (item.userid === data[k]) {
                   this.found = true;
               }
            }
            if (!this.found) {
               data.push(item.userid);
               $('<tr origclass="even_row" class="even_row">\n\\n\
                            <td>' + item.userid + '</td>\n\
                            <td>' + item.alias + '</td>\n\
                            <td>' + item.surname + '</td>\n\
                            </tr>').insertAfter('.nilar');
            }
            this.found = false;                
        }
    } else {
        for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
            data.push(result[j].userid);
        }            
    }        
}

window.setTimeout(function() {
   window.setInterval(function() {
      pullNotification();
   }, 3000);
   pullNotification();
}, 1000);  
});
```

**PHP**

```
function getJsonUsers() {
   $timeStart = time();
   $newData = false;
   $users_data = array(); 

   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';   

   while (!$newData && (time() - $timeStart) < 10) {
         usleep ( 10000000 );
         $db_res = DBselect($sql);
         while ($user = DBfetch($db_res)) {            
               $users_data[] = $user;
               $newData = true;
         }               
   }    
   return $users_data;  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is performing a long-polling technique.  The server gets a client request, the server method is checking for any changes in data, and when found, returns it to the client.  In short-polling, the client is constantly sending requests for data on a timer basis; in long-polling, the client makes one request and waits for the server to return any new data it has.

For example, in your method getJsonUsers(), it is running a query that looks for new data, and upon finding it, returns it to the user.  If it doesn't find data, it waits a finite amount of time, and tries again.  The client won't get notified of anything until data is actually returned, or it will timeout.  This is a normal pattern for long-polling.  If your program was using a short-polling technique, the server method would just return (either data or no data, depending on the results of the query you're running), and not wait to actually get *something* to give back to the client.

Your client code on the other hand, in the case of short-polling, would keep making requests to the server, and after a certain amount of time, would make another request.  Long-polling uses an event-based mechanism (that is, it waits for data to be present prior to returning) for alerting the client of data, whereas the short-polling method just keeps hitting the server regardless of what it gets back or not.

This website has good information on polling techniques, including an example of long-polling:  [CoderTalks:  Long Polling vs Short Polling](http://codertalks.com/long-polling-vs-short-polling/)

Comment: Instead of just providing a link that contains information, elaborate on the information here while directly connecting and trying to improve the OP's code.

Comment: @SirPython Thank you for the suggestion; I added additional information instead of relying more upon the linked article.  I appreciate your advice and I hope the extended answer can help the OP more.